# What is the difference between MENU_NORMAL_ITEM and MENU_CALLBACK?

Tags: drupal

What is the difference between MENU_NORMAL_ITEM and MENU_CALLBACK?

Answer (score 14):

The more precise answer is that `hook_menu()` creates router items, and also menu links are generated. `MENU_NORMAL_ITEM` generates a menu link which will appear in the navigation menu, while `MENU_CALLBACK` does not add a menu link, so it won't appear in the menu.

Comment: What I like to point out is that hook_menu is a little confusing - it both defines the router that says that path X goes to function Y, but it also defines the navigation menu that displays the related links to the page you're on.

Answer (score 7):

`MENU_NORMAL_ITEM` creates a menu item while `MENU_CALLBACK` doesn't. That is the only difference.

Comment: why in the world would I want to add a menu item that isn't a menu item?

Comment: Because 'menu' is a bit of a misnomer. The menu-system is the Drupal 7 router. So if you want an URL to execute a specific module/function then you need to create a MENU_CALLBACK menu item.

Answer (score 4):

Addition to the above comment, MENU_CALLBACK can be used in some scenarios such as AJAX.
Example:  example.com/ajax/country_list is a MENU_CALLBACK which returns a list of countries in HTML,JSON or XML format... This menu doesn't appear in the browser.
You can visit http://api.drupal.org/api/group/menu/6 for more information.

Comment: This is the only answer that sheds any light on why there is a MENU_CALLBACK.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal maps urls to functions.
Means you need a function for every URL.The function is mostly present in a module.
ex mysite/add will have a mapping to a function in a module.
Many cases we don't want the URL as as a menu item but intend to use it for other purposes. The best example being a Ajax callback.
Ex: you have an auto-suggest form which calls a function suggest in the server.The front end Ajax will need a url to fire the request.Let the url be www.mysite/suggest
This is the case when you need a MENU_CALLBACK

```
 function example_menu() {
      $items['suggest'] = array(
      'page callback' => 'example_suggest',
      'access callback' => TRUE,
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
     );
     return $items;
   }
   function example_suggest() {
     //you can return the autosuggested items to the page
   }
```